# Taking SnapShot in MPMovieController in iOS

Tags: ios

I am working on a project where I take the HTTP streaming video and display it in the `MPMoviePlayerController`. And I have to take the snapshot of that streaming video.

I used following code to do that, but I get only nil value.

```
UIImage *thumbnail = [mpPlayer thumbnailImageAtTime:yourMoviePlayerObject.currentPlaybackTime 
                       timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use UIGraphics to take screenshot:

```
CGSize imageSize = set_image_size_here;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);
CGContextRef imageContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[mpPlayer.view.layer renderInContext:imageContext];
```

Retrieve screenshot image

```
UIImage *imagefinal = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```